# VBA to hide multiple columns on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 6 sheets. Sheets 2-5 contain columns I want to hide or unhide. Sheet 6 contains keys and I don't want to alter it. On sheet 1 I have columns A and B. Column A contains the names of headers which are present on sheets 2-5. In column B is a drop down for "hide/unhide". I have tried to write a macro to achieve this, but my sequential If statements error with an if block error message. Any help gratefully received. I ideally want to use an event handler so that the code runs when the values in B1 to B8 on Sheet 1 are changed, automatically. I have tried inserting the below code as both a module, and as code specific to Sheet 1, but no success. None of the data sets are in arrays.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim hideFtoJ As Boolean, hideKtoL As Boolean, hideMtoS As Boolean
    
    ' Check if the value of cell B1 has changed
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        ' Check the new value of cell B1
        If Target.Value = "HIDE" Then
            hideFtoJ = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "SHOW" Then
            hideFtoJ = False
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Check if the value of cell B2 has changed
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        ' Check the new value of cell B2
        If Target.Value = "HIDE" Then
            hideKtoL = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "SHOW" Then
            hideKtoL = False
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Check if the value of cell B3 has changed
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        ' Check the new value of cell B3
        If Target.Value = "HIDE" Then
            hideMtoS = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "SHOW" Then
            hideMtoS = False
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Loop through all the worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ' Hide or unhide columns F to J based on the value of B1
            If hideFtoJ = True Then
                ws.Range("F:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                ws.Range("F:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
            
            ' Hide or unhide columns K to L based on the value of B2
            If hideKtoL = True Then
                ws.Range("K:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                ws.Range("K:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
            
            ' Hide or unhide columns M to S based on the value of B3
            If hideMtoS = True Then
                ws.Range("M:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                ws.Range("M:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: Does the debugger point to a specific line when the "sequential If statements error with an if block error message"?

Comment: You wrote "the code runs when the values in B1 to B8 on Sheet 1 are changed", but your code clarifies only first three column groups to be hidden/unhidden ("F:J", "K:L" and "M:S"). Since there are different number of columns in each group, how to know what specific columns should be handled by the rest of the cells (B4 to B8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, copy the next code in `Sheet1` code module. You did not answer my clarification question related to columns to be handled for the cases of changes in the range "B4:B8". Please, adapt the specific array from the fourth element to the eighth one:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim rngTg As Range: Set rngTg = Me.Range("B1:B8")
     
     If Not Intersect(Target, rngTg) Is Nothing Then
        'columns ranges from the fourth one should be adapted to your needs:
        Dim arrCols(): arrCols = Array("F:J", "K:L", "M:S", "T:V", "W:Z", "AA:AC", "AD:AE", "AF:AH")
        If Target.Value = "HIDE" Then
            hideCols CStr(arrCols(Target.column - 1)), True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "SHOW" Then
            hideCols CStr(arrCols(Target.column - 1)), False
        End If
     End If
End Sub

Sub hideCols(strCols As String, boolVis As Boolean)
    Dim arrSheets(): arrSheets = Array(2, 3, 4, 5) 'array of sheets to be processed
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Worksheets(arrSheets)
        sh.Range(strCols).EntireColumn = boolVis
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code FaneDuru. Mine previously debugged on the first For each ws statement. Apologies for my ignorance - but how do I insert a module specific to sheet 1 code module? I previously inserted a module, and viewed sheet 1 code then pasted in. Neither  way worked. @VBasic2008 apologies too. Sure your code is good and my implementation is at fault.

Comment: @Rob E Such an event works **only in a sheet code module**. To place the code there, please proceed in the next way: 1. Activate `Sheet1` (in Excel). 2. Right click on the sheet name (to the sheet bottom side) and choose `View Code`. 3. Copy the above code in the opening window and  start playing with changes in the range "B1:B8". Take care to adapt `arrCols()` with your necessary columns address, starting from the fourth array element to the eighth one. It will work, anyhow, but it will hide the columns addresses which I randomly placed there...

Comment: @Rob E Didn't you find some time to place the event in its natural place and test the code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: your code was great - thank you so much. I didn't have time to test it yesterday as I was on site all day and didn't have my usual IT access. Apologies for not coming back sooner with the thumbs up. Solved.

Comment: @Rob E Glad I could help! But I like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box to make it **accepted answer**. In this way somebody searching for a similar issue, will know that the solution works. And I am not talking about my code! You received two solutions. Please, mark as accepted one of them. The one you like more... Not necessarily to be mine!

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide Columns in Other Worksheets

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim tCells(): tCells = Array("B1", "B2", "B3")
    Dim HideCols(): HideCols = Array("F:J", "K:L", "M:S")
    
    Dim SheetIndexes(): SheetIndexes = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(tCells) To UBound(tCells)
        If Not Intersect(Me.Range(tCells(n)), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next n
    If n > UBound(tCells) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim hCols As String: hCols = HideCols(n)
    Dim IsHidden As Boolean
    IsHidden = StrComp(CStr(Target.Value), "HIDE", vbTextCompare) = 0
    
    For n = LBound(SheetIndexes) To UBound(SheetIndexes)
        Me.Parent.Worksheets(SheetIndexes(n)).Columns(hCols).Hidden = IsHidden
    Next n
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey VBasic2008. Can't get this to work for me. How do I trigger this to run when the I put values change? Currently the columns remain unchanged

Comment: In VBE, open `Project Explorer`. Double-click on the first worksheet. The window that has opened is the sheet module where you have to copy this code. It runs automatically as per your requirement. Sometimes, when you 'play too much' with event codes, events get disabled and none of them work. You can enable them by using the following line in a new sub: `Application.EnableEvents = True`.